Recommended method to backup headless server?
Strangely enough, my search didn't turn up any good hint. Therefore I ask all of you:
How do I backup a headless server? It has little space left on the SSD, but that doesn't matter, since it has some huge drives for data. It is headless by default, so it can't accommodate a monitor. I can only ssh into it.
Now I am looking for the best method, to backup the running system completely onto one of the data drives. The backup should be as complete as ever possible, so that I could write back everything onto the system SSD, eventually after a failure or replacement of the same; preferably including boot sector (MBR) and the same partitions.

If you want to create snapshots, rsnapshot. I use it to backup many headless server over SSH. Without the snapshots feature it basically acts like rsync, so at that point you may just use rsync. On local non-headless machines, I use it as a systemd service that backups the system on shutdown. By latching the systemd service correctly (just before / is unmounted) you should be able to fully image / while nothing is writing to it.

"Best" is subjective. "Best" is the method YOU will be able to use successfully on the bad day when you really need it. "Best" is different for everybody. Pro Tip: Take notes, because you surely won't remember the steps to restore from that backup on that bad day.

Thanks, @kos. Sounds like you got what I tried to ask for.
Now, could you please specify what you mean with "By latching the systemd service correctly (just before / is unmounted) you should be able to fully image / while nothing is writing to it." That's actually what I had in mind. How does one do that, please?

Beware, I've never tried this. But root mount's systemd mount unit should be -.mount, so if you set up a service to run just before -.mount is to be terminated, you should be able to image / when every other serivice that depends on -.mount has terminated. You could try and swap -.mount for mnt-nas-backup.mount in the service I provided as an asnwer to my own question here (again, mind that that service is supposed to run just on shutdown. If you want it to run on reboot as well, just remove the systemctl / grep guard)
